# Visual Studio 2005 - strange characters rendered for ANSI text

Tags: visual-studio-2005, character-encoding, rendering

Has anyone seen this odd text rendering issue in VS2005 before?

[image http://tinyurl.com/3y2ebze](http://tinyurl.com/3y2ebze)

The first line of using statements actually says "using System;". If I copy the line as it is displayed and paste into notepad, the text appears correctly, so clearly the character codes are correct. In addition, the solution compiles and runs correctly.

I was thinking it might be due to ClearCase using a different character encoding as all the solutions we're using were freshly checked-out yesterday on to a new build machine, but this is only happening in 2 of our ~30 solutions.

Incidentally the same .cs files when opened in VS2008 render correctly on this machine, could this be a corruption in VS2005?

Comment: Try opening the file in an editor (hex-editor, vim, whatever) that shows you what's acutally written in the file (i.e. what characters the little squares really are)... Looks like the term `using System;` is in a different encoding than `using System.IO;`. If really ClearCase modified the files, I'd throw it away: the VCS never ever might change anything in the sources...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As mentioned, copying and pasting the text from VS, or opening the file in notepad displays the text fine. In fact, the code compiles and runs ok. It seems to be an issue with VS2005's text rendering. I'm going to try re-installing VS2005 this afternoon and see if this fixes it.

Comment: After some more investigation it appears to be related to Resharper, if I un-install it, the problem goes away. Re-install again and it returns. This is weird as I've been using R# for a few years and have never seen this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install latest service pack to VS2005.

Comment: Thanks very much Ilya, SP1 fixed the problem.